# How to get the underlying socket read buffer size?

Tags: c, openssl

There's an api for raw socket:

```
int sz;
ioctlsocket(sock, FIONREAD, &sz); 
::recv(sock, buff, sz, 0);
```

the **ioctlsocket** can be used to get the incoming buffer size, but how to get it with openssl:

```
int sz = what?
SSL_read(pSSL, buff, sz);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how to get [incoming buffer size] with openssl?

OpenSSL uses `BIO`s. There's a `BIO_get_write_buf_size` for the write buffer, but no corresponding control for the read buffer. You can set the read buffer size with `BIO_set_read_buffer_size`. But I believe that sets the buffer for the `BIO`, and not the I/O buffer on the socket. See `struct bio_bio_st` in `crypto/bio/bss_bio.c` and the docs at [`BIO_f_buffer(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_f_buffer.html) and [`BIO_s_bio(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_bio.html).

You should be able to call `BIO_get_fd` on the `BIO` to get the underlying socket, and then use `ioctl` or `ioctlsocket`. You can find the `BIO` in the `SSL*`. OpenSSL conveniently has `SSL_get_rbio` and `SSL_get_wbio`. From `ssl/ssl.h`:

```
struct ssl_st
    {
    /* protocol version
     * (one of SSL2_VERSION, SSL3_VERSION, TLS1_VERSION, DTLS1_VERSION)
     */
    int version;
    int type; /* SSL_ST_CONNECT or SSL_ST_ACCEPT */

    const SSL_METHOD *method; /* SSLv3 */

    /* There are 2 BIO's even though they are normally both the
     * same.  This is so data can be read and written to different
     * handlers */

#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_BIO
    BIO *rbio; /* used by SSL_read */
    BIO *wbio; /* used by SSL_write */
    BIO *bbio; /* used during session-id reuse to concatenate messages */
#else
    char *rbio; /* used by SSL_read */
    char *wbio; /* used by SSL_write */
    char *bbio;
#endif
    /* This holds a variable that indicates what we were doing
     * when a 0 or -1 is returned.  This is needed for
     * non-blocking IO so we know what request needs re-doing when
     * in SSL_accept or SSL_connect */
    int rwstate;
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you jww for the code and the title correcting.

Here's my code

```
// create ssl connection
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method()); 
pSSL = SSL_new(ctx);
sbio = BIO_new_socket(raw_socket, BIO_NOCLOSE); 
SSL_set_bio(pSSL, sbio, sbio); 
SSL_set_fd(pSSL, raw_socket);
SSL_connect(pSSL)

// send
SSL_write(pSSL, s.c_str(), s.length());

// receive
int sock_fd;
int r = BIO_get_fd(sbio, &sock_fd); // <------------------
cout << r << endl; // output -2
```

or even use the **raw_socket** that used in BIO_new_socket and SSL_set_fd

```
ulong sz = 0;
while(sz == 0) { // <--------- it loops forever, even server echoes data
    if(ioctlsocket(raw_socket, FIONREAD, &sz) != 0) {
        throw "get_recv_size";
    }
    Sleep(0);
}
```

the **raw_socket** and the underlying socket used in BIO are different ones?

Answer (score 0):

The OP essentially asked "How big should the buffer be that's passed to SSL_read?" Building off of jww's answer, and - this is key - if you don't mind using things that may change in future versions of OpenSSL, then it's pretty easy to get at the read buffer size.

*Note : This is based on openssl 1.0.2e*

Get the BIO as jww describes using SSL_get_rbio(). The BIO sizes are stored in a BIO_F_BUFFER_CTX within the BIO. This can be seen in the file crypto/bio/bf_cuff.c:

```
static int buffer_new(BIO *bi)
{
    BIO_F_BUFFER_CTX *ctx;

    ctx = (BIO_F_BUFFER_CTX *)OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(BIO_F_BUFFER_CTX));
    if (ctx == NULL)
        return (0);
    ctx->ibuf = (char *)OPENSSL_malloc(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (ctx->ibuf == NULL) {
        OPENSSL_free(ctx);
        return (0);
    }
    ctx->obuf = (char *)OPENSSL_malloc(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (ctx->obuf == NULL) {
        OPENSSL_free(ctx->ibuf);
        OPENSSL_free(ctx);
        return (0);
    }
    ctx->ibuf_size = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
    ctx->obuf_size = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
    ctx->ibuf_len = 0;
    ctx->ibuf_off = 0;
    ctx->obuf_len = 0;
    ctx->obuf_off = 0;

    bi->init = 1;
    bi->ptr = (char *)ctx;
    bi->flags = 0;
    return (1);
}
```

Fetching the read buffer size can be accomplished by using:

```
((BIO_F_BUFFER_CTX*)bio->ptr)->ibuf_size;
```

Where *bio* is a variable representing the BIO to query. The *ptr* variable needs to be cast back from char*.

Note that this applies to any BIO's, like the one returned from BIO_new_ssl_connect( ctx ), etc.